# MFC CInternetSession LARGEADDRESSAWARE error 12157

Tags: c++, mfc

I am experimenting with adding >2 GB support to some Win32 applications. I've set /LARGEADDRESSAWARE in the linker and have switched on MEM_TOP_DOWN AllocationPreference on this x64 system. All seems fine until I try to access HTTPS locations using a CInternetSession. When CHttpFile::SendRequest is called, an exception is thrown:

> Warning: throwing CInternetException for error 12157

Calling GetErrorMessage on the exception returns

> An error occurred in the secure channel support

I've created a small MFC Dialog application with just the CInternetSession and related classes and still get the error if I link with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE. It works correctly without that flag.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known error? If so, I'm failing to think of the search terms to find anyone talking about the issue.

The HTTPS connection works if I remove the AllocationPreference setting from the registry and reboot. Is this a LARGEADDRESSAWARE bug in afxinet?